# If else statement fails

Tags: java

```
for (h = 1; h <= userInput; h++) {
    while (h <= userInput) {

        System.out.println("\nPick a Y coordinate: (1 - " + row + ")");
        try {
            userInput2 = stdin.nextInt();
            if (userInput2 > 0 && userInput2 <= row) {
            } else {
                System.out.println("Make sure you only choose a"
                        + " coordinate between 1 and " + row);
            }
        } catch (Exception f) {
            System.out.println("Make sure your only choosing a coordinate"
                    + " between 1 and " + row);
            stdin.next();
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println("\nPick a X coordinate: (1 - " + column + ")");

        try {
            userInput3 = stdin.nextInt();
            if (userInput3 > 0 && userInput3 <= column) {
            } else {
                System.out.println("Make sure you only choose a"
                        + " coordinate between 1 and " + column);
            }
        } catch (Exception g) {
            System.out.println("Make sure your only choosing a coordinate"
                    + " between 1 and " + column);
            stdin.next();
            continue;
        }

        if (userGuesses[userInput2][userInput3] == false) {
            userGuesses[userInput2][userInput3] = true;
        }

        if (h == userInput) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You've already chosen that coordinate coward!"
                    + " Try again!");
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason that last `if else` statement always gets printed out (the SoP that is apart of the else). Even if it's my first time selecting the coordinates for this program. I'm really new to programming and maybe I've made a rookie mistake that's glaringly obvious to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the nested `while` loop. It's preventing `h` from changing,

```
for ( h = 1 ; h <= userInput; h++) { 
    // while (h <= userInput) {
    // ...
    // }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I fixed it and added a couple h--; where appropriate.

Comment: I'm still getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException even though i have the catches with the exceptions. any idea why that might be?

Comment: Make sure the values are within the array's length. Remember that valid array indexes are `0` to `length - 1`.